# Header Glitching Between a Range of Pixels

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

So I have a web application I have written with ASP .NET and I try in the `_layout.cshtml` to adjust the header and footer to the type of the screen (Mobile, Tablet and PC).
I have managed to make it look good for PC and Moblie and it looks like that:

**For x pixels over 1200px (including) it looks like:**
[image]

**For x pixels below 575px (including) it looks like:**
[image]

&
[image]

**BUT** in between it looks like this:
[image]

 &
[image]

I am not so much of a `frontend` programmer yet so I went to `ChatGPT` for some assistance and it provided some.
But  I can't seem to understand why it does not work now.

### Here is my `_layout.cshtml` code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using SvivaTeamVersion3.Areas.Identity.Data;
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SvivaTeam</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">SvivaTeam</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                       
                        @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Manage
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <a asp-action="ListUsers" asp-controller="Administration"
                               class="dropdown-item">Users</a>
                                    <a asp-action="ListRoles" asp-controller="Administration"
                               class="dropdown-item">Roles</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h6 style="visibility:hidden">Hidden text.</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select id="lang-switch" class="navbar-nav">
                            <option id="lan1" value="EN"> English</option>
                            <option id="lan2" value="HE" selected> Hebrew</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <style>
            .navbar {
                padding-top: 0.5rem;
                padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
            }

            .navbar-brand {
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }

            .navbar-nav {
                margin-left: auto;
            }

            .nav-link {
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                margin-left: 1rem;
                margin-right: 1rem;
            }

            .footer {
                padding-top: 1rem;
                padding-bottom: 1rem;
                text-align: center;
            }


            @@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
                .navbar {
                    padding-top: 0.25rem;
                    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
                }

                .navbar-brand {
                    font-size: 1.2rem;
                }

                .navbar-nav {
                    margin-left: 0;
                    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
                }

                .nav-link {
                    font-size: 1rem;
                    margin-left: 0.5rem;
                    margin-right: 0.5rem;
                }
                .footer {
                    padding-top: 0.5rem;
                    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
                }
            }

            @@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
                .navbar {
                  padding-top: 0.5rem;
                  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
                }

                .navbar-brand {
                  font-size: 1.5rem;
                }

                .navbar-nav {
                  margin-left: auto;
                }

                .nav-link {
                  font-size: 1.2rem;
                  margin-left: 1rem;
                  margin-right: 1rem;
                }

                .footer {
                  padding-top: 1rem;
                  padding-bottom: 1rem;
                  text-align: center;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 text-center">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                &copy; 2022 - SvivaTeam - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a> <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TermsOfService">TOS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

What do I do to make the glitched part look like the part of the mobile?

### EDIT - UPDATE:

After some more digging, I have found that the CSS for the nav bar is controlled by a file called `bootstrap.min` which is empty but my guess is that it is being generated when I start my solution.

Comment: It looks like the `.navbar-brand` anchor element has the CSS property `overflow-wrap` set to `anywhere` and the CSS property `white-space` is `unset`. Can you check in the console what the CSS properties of the `.navbar-brand` anchor element are? The styles you included in your post only show font styling the `.navbar-brand` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that I have 3 classes that control the behavior of the navigation bar, and those are the classes:

- `navbar-light` - The class for the mobile version
- `navbar-expand-sm` & `navbar-toggleable-sm`- The classes for the desktop version.

So I had an idea, to add a function that will check the screen's (browser's) size and add/remove the classes accordingly.

Here is the final code:

```
function updateNav(nav) {
    if (window.screen.width >= 1200) {
        nav.classList.remove('navbar-light');
        nav.classList.add('navbar-expand-sm');
        nav.classList.add('navbar-toggleable-sm');
    } else {
        nav.classList.remove('navbar-expand-sm');
        nav.classList.remove('navbar-toggleable-sm');
        nav.classList.add('navbar-light');
    }
 }

var nav = document.getElementById("navigation-bar");

updateNav(nav);

window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
    updateNav(nav);
});
```